# Can the Oracle-Text OR be replaced with a comma?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I have incorporated user-accessible Oracle-Text functionality within my application and I noticed that the comma `,` can be used in place of `OR` or the pipe `|` character.

Searching on 'red OR green OR blue' returns the same results as 'red|green|blue' or 'red,green,blue'.

I reviewed the [Oracle-Text Contains](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm) documentation and tried my favourite search engine but I did not find any documentation to support or negate my findings and the comma `,` is never mentioned.

I would like to mention the comma `,` as an option for my users but don't want to without some supporting documentation.

Comment: The link to the document that you posted has the comma as the `ACCUMulate` operator.  it has the lowest precedence, but affects the scoring of the returned items, with the higher number of possible matches returning a higher score ("cat,dog" would score something with cat and dog higher than either cat or dog on it's own)

Comment: @Jad, Bingo, I totally missed that.   If you turn your comment into an answer then I will give that to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the document that you posted has the comma as the [ACCUMulate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#CCREF0302) operator.

The Accumulate operator is the operator with the lowest precedence, but it affects the scoring of the returned items, with the higher number of possible matches returning a higher score

e.g. the accumulate action of `cat,dog` would score something with both cat *and* dog higher than a string with either cat *xor* dog in it